# F#, MailboxProcessor and Async running slow?

Tags: f#, mailboxprocessor

**Background.**

I am trying to figure out MailboxProcessor. The idea is to use it as a some kind of state machine and pass arguments around between the states and then quit. Some parts are going to have async communication so I made a Sleep there.
It's a console application, making a Post does nothing because main thread quits and kills everything behind it. I am making a PostAndReply in main. 
Also, I have tried without

```
let sleepWorkflow  = async
```

, doesn't make any difference.

**Questions.**

(I am probably doing something wrong)

1. Go24 is not async. Changing RunSynchronously to StartImmediate makes no visible difference. The end should be somewhere below GetMe instead. At the same time Done is printed after Fetch. Isn't the control supposed t be returned to the main thread on sleep?

   Go24, wait
   go24 1, end
   Fetch 1
   Done
   GetMe
   ...
2. Run time is terrible slow. Without delay in Fetch it's about 10s (stopwatch). I thought F# threads are lightweight and should use threadpool.
   According to debugger it takes appr 1s to create every and it looks like real threads.

Also, changing to [1..100] will "pause" the program for 100s, according to ProcessExplorer 100 threads are created during that time and only then everything is printed. I would actually prefer fewer threads and slow increase.

Code.

Program.fs

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =


    let a = Mailbox.MessageBasedCounter.DoGo24 1
    let a = Mailbox.MessageBasedCounter.DoFetch 1
    let b = Mailbox.MessageBasedCounter.GetMe

    let task i  = async {
        //Mailbox.MessageBasedCounter.DoGo24 1
        let a = Mailbox.MessageBasedCounter.DoFetch i
        return a
        }

    let stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew()

    let x = 
        [1..10]
            |> Seq.map task
            |> Async.Parallel
            |> Async.RunSynchronously

    stopWatch.Stop()
    printfn "%f" stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds

    printfn "a: %A" a
    printfn "b: %A" b

    printfn "x: %A" x
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Mailbox.fs

```
module Mailbox

#nowarn "40"

type parserMsg =
    | Go24 of int
    | Done
    | Fetch of int * AsyncReplyChannel<string>
    | GetMe of AsyncReplyChannel<string>


type MessageBasedCounter () = 

    /// Create the agent
    static let agent = MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox -> 

        // the message processing function
        let rec messageLoop() = async{
            let! msg = inbox.Receive()

            match msg with 
            | Go24 n ->
                let sleepWorkflow  = async{
                    printfn "Go24, wait"
                    do! Async.Sleep 4000 
                    MessageBasedCounter.DoDone() // POST Done.
                    printfn "go24 %d, end" n
                    return! messageLoop()
                } 
                Async.RunSynchronously sleepWorkflow
            | Fetch (i, repl) ->
                let sync = async{
                    printfn "Fetch %d" i
                    do! Async.Sleep 1000
                    repl.Reply( "Reply Fetch " + i.ToString() ) // Reply to the caller 
                    return! messageLoop()
                }
                Async.RunSynchronously sync

            | GetMe (repl) ->
                let sync = async{
                    printfn "GetMe"
                    repl.Reply( "GetMe" ) // Reply to the caller 
                    return! messageLoop()
                }
                Async.RunSynchronously sync
            | Done -> 
                let sync = async{
                    printfn "Done"
                    return! messageLoop()
                }
                Async.RunSynchronously sync 
            }

        // start the loop 
        messageLoop()
        )

    // public interface to hide the implementation
    static member DoDone () = agent.Post( Done )
    static member DoGo24 (i:int) = agent.Post( Go24(i) )
    static member DoFetch (i:int) = agent.PostAndReply( fun reply -> Fetch(i, reply) )
    static member GetMe = agent.PostAndReply( GetMe )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not necessarily sure that this is the main problem, but the nested asyncs and `Async.RunSynchrously` in the agent code look suspicious.

You do not need to create a nested async - you can just call asynchronous operations in the body of the `match` clauses directly:

```
// the message processing function
let rec messageLoop() = async{
  let! msg = inbox.Receive()

  match msg with 
  | Go24 n ->
      printfn "Go24, wait"
      do! Async.Sleep 4000 
      MessageBasedCounter.DoDone()
      printfn "go24 %d, end" n
      return! messageLoop()

  | Fetch (i, repl) ->
      (...)
```

Aside from that, it is important to understand that the agent has exactly one instance of the body computation running. So, if you block the body of the agent, all other operations will be queued.

If you want to start some task (like the synchronous operations) in the background and resume the agent immediately, you can use `Async.Start` inside the body (but be sure to call the main loop recursively in the main part of the body):

```
  | Go24 n ->
      // Create work item that will run in the background
      let work = async {
        printfn "Go24, wait"
        do! Async.Sleep 4000 
        MessageBasedCounter.DoDone()
        printfn "go24 %d, end" n }
      // Queue the work in a thread pool to be processed
      Async.Start(work)
      // Continue the message loop, waiting for other messages
      return! messageLoop()
```

Comment: Aha, thank you. I was trying to resume the agent like you say. 
Looks like my mistake is to call return! messageLoop() inside the async. That doesn't resume the agent.

I am using the outer async as a workaround because it is required to Seq.map as Parallell. Running
    let x = [1..10] |> Seq.map Mailbox.MessageBasedCounter.DoFetch
breaks the program before reaching 10.
    List.map
Runs to 10 without problems. Just a funny moment.